# int android.view.View.getVisibility() on a null object reference when call startactivity in onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

I am implementing a feature, click a menu item and then jump to a new activity, here is code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.expert_mode:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ExpertModeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the activity declared here:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import Utils.AbstractLogger;
import Utils.Logcat;

public class ExpertModeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    protected AbstractLogger mLogger = new Logcat("ExpertModeActivity", true);

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread t, @NonNull Throwable e) {
        mLogger.error(e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expert_mode);
    }
}
```

in manifest.xml, i declared the activity like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.ltd.lifesearchapp.DebugActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.ltd.lifesearchapp.ResultExplorerActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.ltd.lifesearchapp.ExpertModeActivity"/>
```

now, when I run this module, I got this error:

```
2020-10-19 16:07:17.893 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

2020-10-19 16:07:17.894 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.getHostVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1856)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.894 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleAppVisibility(ViewRootImpl.java:1491)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.895 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4928)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.895 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.895 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.896 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.896 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.897 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)

2020-10-19 16:07:17.897 29154-29154/com.ltd.lifesearchapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I find some answer about problem like this, but I still have no idea.
I am confused about that, does anyone know the reason of this problem?

Comment: sorry, I first use stackoverflow to ask question, and some code is not well formatted

Comment: on which line you are getting this error, this code is not clear as per your crash log

Comment: in fact, there is no valid error log for this error, that's why i got confused

Comment: as you see, that's the whole.The error log does not indicate which line of code was the cause of the error, i got confused because i can't locate the problem

Comment: when i run the app, i click the menu, and in onoptionsitemselected, i successfully jump into another activity, the startactivity successfully return, and then this error has occured

Comment: Do You have any code based on Visibility in another activity’s oncreate?

Comment: no, but when i run this code in huawei phone, everything is ok